# Drawing an activation stack in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw an activation stack. I am really bat at TikZ, so I hope you can help me out.

[image: Activation Stack Diagram]

As you can see, there are four boxes stacked one on top of the other. Each box has a name, put on the right, and is made of an upper part, where variables and numbers are displayed, and a lower part which is divided in two halves. The left half has to contain an arrow pointing to one of the boxes placed under it, the right half contains only a few characters. The box at the bottom hdoesn't have a *pointy* arrow, because it doesn't have to reference anything.

I really hope you can help me out, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}
\usepackage{cancel}

\tikzset{box/.style={draw, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm, outer sep=0pt, font=\ttfamily, align=left},
    minibox/.style={box, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=5mm, anchor=north west},
    pointer/.style={fill, circle, minimum size=2mm, inner sep=0pt},
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex]

\node[box, label=right:$P_2$] (P2) {};
\node[minibox] at (P2.south west) (P2-1) {};
\node[minibox] at (P2.south) (P2-2) {};

\node[box, label=right:$P_4$, below=1cm of P2] (P4) {};
\node[minibox] at (P4.south west) (P4-1) {};
\node[minibox] at (P4.south) (P4-2) {};

\node[box, label=right:$P_3$, below=1cm of P4] (P3) {a/d(p1)=0\\b=\cancel{3} 2};
\node[minibox] at (P3.south west) (P3-1) {};
\node[minibox] at (P3.south) (P3-2) {};

\node[box, label=right:$P_4$, below=1cm of P3] (P1) {a=3\\b=2\\c=1\\d=0};
\node[minibox] at (P1.south west) (P1-1) {};
\node[minibox] at (P1.south) (P1-2) {\# 6};

\draw[->] (P2-1.center) coordinate[pointer]  -- ([xshift=-10mm]P2-1.west) |- ([yshift=-8mm]P3.north west);
\draw[->] (P4-1.center) coordinate[pointer]  -- ([xshift=-5mm]P4-1.west) |- ([yshift=-4mm]P3.north west);
\draw[->] (P3-1.center) coordinate[pointer]  -- ([xshift=-5mm]P3-1.west) |- ([yshift=-4mm]P1.north west);
\draw[-|] (P1-1.center) coordinate[pointer]  -- ([xshift=-5mm]P1-1.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You may find this excerpt from a book I write useful. Please do not use as is.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\newcommand\kk[1]{\textcolor{RoyalBlue}{\text{\textup{\textbf{\texttt{#1}}}}}}
\newcommand\cc[1]{\textcolor{Sepia}{\text{\textup{\textbf{\texttt{#1}}}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[start chain=going left,node distance=0pt]
\def\width{9ex}

\tikzstyle{frame}=[
    font=\scriptsize,
    %text width=7ex,
    draw,
    on chain,
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split parts=20,
    rectangle split part align={center, left},
    rectangle split empty part height=0ex,
    rectangle split empty part depth=0ex,
    rectangle split empty part width=0ex,
]

\node (main) [frame,
    rectangle split parts=5,
    rectangle split part fill={Fuchsia!30,brown!30, brown!30, yellow!40} 
] {%
\nodepart{one} 
  \begin{minipage}{\width}
    \centering saved state of O/S 
  \end{minipage}
\nodepart{two} \kk{int} \cc{argc}
\nodepart{three} \kk{char} \cc{**argv}
\nodepart{four} 
  \begin{minipage}{14ex} \centering
   \kk{int} \cc{a[500]}\medskip\\
    \tikz{\node (a) [
    draw,
    font=\tiny,
    text width=12ex,
    rectangle split parts,
    rectangle split part fill={yellow},
    rectangle split part align={left,left,left,left}
  ]{%
    \nodepart{one} \cc{a[499]}
    \nodepart{two} \cc{a[498]}
    \nodepart{three} {\begin{minipage}{6ex}\quad\\\mbox{\quad}\large\qquad$\vdots$\quad\\\scriptsize\end{minipage}}
    \nodepart{four}\cc{a[1]}
    \nodepart{five}\cc{a[0]}
  };}
  \end{minipage}
\nodepart{five} 
  \begin{minipage}{14ex} \centering
   \kk{int} \cc{b[200]}\\
    \tikz{\node [
    draw,
    text width=12ex,
    font=\tiny,
    rectangle split parts=3,
    rectangle split part fill={yellow},
    rectangle split part align={left,left,left,left}
  ]{%
    \nodepart{one} \cc{b[199]}
    \nodepart{two} {\large $\vdots$}
    \nodepart{three}\cc{b[0]}
  };}
  \end{minipage}
};

\node (sort) [frame,
    rectangle split parts=3,
    text width=10ex,
    rectangle split part fill={Fuchsia!30,brown!30, brown!30} 
] {%
\nodepart{one} 
  \begin{minipage}{\width}
    \centering saved state of \cc{main} 
  \end{minipage}
\nodepart{two} \kk{int} \cc{*a}
\nodepart{three} \kk{int} \cc{n}
};

\node (qsort1) [frame,
    rectangle split parts=5,
    rectangle split part fill={Fuchsia!30,teal!30,brown!30, brown!30, yellow!40} 
] {%
\nodepart{one} 
  \begin{minipage}{\width}
    \centering saved state of \cc{sort} 
  \end{minipage}
\nodepart{two}   \kk{void} \cc{*bp} \quad
\nodepart{three}   \kk{int} \cc{from}
\nodepart{four} \kk{int} \cc{to}
\nodepart{five}  \kk{int} \cc{p}
};

\node (qsort2) [frame,  
    rectangle split parts=5,
    rectangle split part fill={Fuchsia!30,teal!30,brown!30, brown!30, yellow!40} 
] {%
\nodepart{one} 
  \begin{minipage}{\width}
    \centering saved state of \cc{qsort}$_1$ 
  \end{minipage}
\nodepart{two}    \kk{void} \cc{*bp}
\nodepart{three}    \kk{int} \cc{from}
\nodepart{four}  \kk{int} \cc{to}
\nodepart{five}   \kk{int} \cc{p}
};

\node (qsort3) [frame,
  text width=9ex,
    rectangle split parts=5,
    rectangle split part fill={Fuchsia!30,teal!30,brown!30, brown!30, yellow!40} 
] {%
\nodepart{one} 
  \begin{minipage}{\width}
    \centering saved state of \cc{qsort}$_2$
  \end{minipage}
\nodepart{two}   \kk{void} \cc{*bp}
\nodepart{three}   \kk{int} \cc{from}
\nodepart{four} \kk{int} \cc{to}
\nodepart{five}  \kk{int} \cc{p}
};

\node (pivot) [frame,
    rectangle split parts=6,
    rectangle split part fill={Fuchsia!30,teal!30,yellow!40}
] {%
\nodepart{one} 
  \begin{minipage}{\width}
    \centering saved state of \cc{qsort}$_3$
  \end{minipage}
\nodepart{two}\kk{void} \cc{*bp}
\nodepart{three}\kk{int} \cc{last}
\nodepart{four}\kk{int} \cc{pivot}
\nodepart{five}\kk{int} \cc{split}
\nodepart{six}\kk{int} \cc{i}
};

\node (swap) [frame,
    rectangle split parts=5,
    rectangle split part fill={Fuchsia!30,teal!30,brown!30, brown!30,yellow!40} 
] {%
\nodepart{one} 
  \begin{minipage}{\width}
    \centering saved state of \cc{pivot} 
  \end{minipage}
\nodepart{two} \kk{void} \cc{*bp}
\nodepart{three} \kk{int} \cc{i}
\nodepart{four} \kk{int} \cc{j}
\nodepart{five} \kk{int} \cc{t}
};

\node(arrow)[on chain]{\Huge$\Leftarrow$};

\node[above=0 pt of main.north,anchor=south,font=\itshape] {main};
\node[above=0 pt of sort.north,anchor=south,font=\itshape] {sort};
\node[above=0 pt of qsort1.north,anchor=south,font=\itshape] {qsort$_1$};
\node[above=0 pt of qsort2.north,anchor=south,font=\itshape] {qsort$_2$};
\node[above=0 pt of qsort3.north,anchor=south,font=\itshape] {qsort$_3$};
\node[above=0 pt of pivot.north,anchor=south,font=\itshape] {pivot};
\node[above=0 pt of swap.north,anchor=south,font=\itshape] {swap};

\tikzstyle{bp}=[draw=black,thin,->,opacity=0.5,>=latex,->] 
\draw[bp] let 
            \p1 = ($(qsort1.two east)!0.1!(qsort1.two) $),
         \p2 =  ($(main.text)+(0,0) $),
           \p3 = ($ (sort.text split)!0.75!(sort.text split east) +(1ex,0)$)
     in 
                (\x1,\y1) -> (\x1,\y2) --(\x3,\y2) -- (\x3,\y3);
;
\draw[bp] let 
            \p1 = ($(qsort2.two east)!0.1!(qsort2.two) $),
         \p2 =  ($(main.text)+(0,1ex) $),
           \p3 = ($ (sort.text split)!0.75!(sort.text split east) +(0ex,0)$)
     in 
                (\x1,\y1)-- (\x1,\y2) --(\x3,\y2) -- (\x3,\y3);

\draw[bp] let 
            \p1 = ($(qsort3.two east)!0.1!(qsort3.two) $),
         \p2 =  ($(main.text)+(0,2ex) $),
           \p3 = ($ (sort.text split)!0.75!(sort.text split east) +(-1ex,0)$)
     in 
                (\x1,\y1)-- (\x1,\y2) --(\x3,\y2) -- (\x3,\y3);
;

\draw[bp] let 
            \p1 = ($(swap.two east)!0.1!(swap.two) $),
            \p2 =  ($(main.text)+(0,3ex) $),
           \p3 = ($ (sort.text split)!0.75!(sort.text split east) +(-2ex,0)$)
     in 
                (\x1,\y1)-> (\x1,\y2) -> (\x3,\y2) -> (\x3,\y3);



\draw[bp] let 
            \p1 = ($(pivot.two east)!0.1!(pivot.two) $),
         \p2 =  ($(main.text)+(0,-2.5ex) $),
           \p3 = ($ (qsort3.text split)!0.75!(qsort3.text split east) +(-1ex,0)$)
     in 
                (\x1,\y1)-- (\x1,\y2) --(\x3,\y2) -- (\x3,\y3);
;

\draw[bp] 
                ($(sort.two east)!0.5!(sort.two) $) |- (a.south west);
;
\end{scope}

\node[fill=gray!10,label=above left:{\scriptsize Legend},font=\scriptsize] at ($(swap)+(0,-20ex)$) {%
  \begin{minipage}{37ex}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix[row sep=1mm, column sep=2mm,column 1/.style={anchor=base west},column 2/.style={anchor=base west},font=\scriptsize]{%
          \node[fill=Fuchsia!30,draw] {Caller's saved state}; & \node[draw,,fill=teal!30] {Back pointer};\\
          \node[draw,fill=brown!30] {Arguments}; &  \node[draw,fill=yellow!40] {Local variables};\\
        }; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
};

\begin{scope}[
every node/.style={ellipse,draw,font=\scriptsize\ttfamily,inner sep=1pt,fill=blue!20}
]
\node (root)
at ($(arrow)+(-24ex,10ex)$)
{$\top$}
[]
child {node {main}}
child {node {sort}
    child {node {swap}}
    child {node {qsort}
        child {node {pivot}}
    }
};
\end{scope}
\node[above=2pt of root,font=\small\bfseries]{Nesting structure};
\node[above=22pt of main,font=\small,xshift=-30ex]{\textbf{Frames on the hardware stac}};
\node[above=10pt of main,font=\footnotesize,xshift=-30ex]{\textit{(grows from high memory to low memory, depicted right to left)}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]